# How to find the th message in telegram with the python-telegram-bot API?

Tags: python, telegram, messaging, python-telegram-bot

How to find the [th](https://www.s-cool.co.uk/gcse/maths/sequences/revise-it/the-nth-term/nth/) message in [telegram](https://www.telegram.org/) with the [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/) API wrapper? I read [the documentation](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/) fully and looked at tutorials such as [this one](https://www.codementor.io/@karandeepbatra/part-1-how-to-create-a-telegram-bot-in-python-in-under-10-minutes-19yfdv4wrq) but to no avail. It follows an [updater mechanism](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.ext.updater.html#telegram.ext.updater.Updater) so I can only receive new messages and reply to them.

I know I can create a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) in which I store all the updates as they come but there's going to be millions of long messages and I was wondering if there was any *proper* way to do this. I am new to this wrapper and would really appreciate any sort of help.
So, how would I write a program to find the th message in a chat with my bot? The message can be either by the user or the bot.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/2476), the Telegram Bot API doesn't offer a `get_message_by_id` method or similar functionality and so `python-telegram-bot` can't either. So if you want to get all the details for every message by its message id, you have no choice than keeping track of them yourself.